# Use of "está" to describe something being good/bad

Tags: gramática, verbos, cópulas

I am learning Spanish with Collins Easy Learning Spanish.
It gives the follow example:

> It is not very good = no es muy bueno
>
> It’s very good =  está muy bueno

Why does only one example use *está* to describe the quality of being good?
Is there a rule that applies to using *está* for discussing good qualities?

Comment: You should specify in which regional Spanish you are interested, since this specific thing depends on that.

Comment: @AlbertMasclans Both Spain and Latin America.

Comment: My favorite is la salsa es picante pero no está caliente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be an incomplete example. As you guess you can use both *ser*/*estar*.

> It is not very good

If we refer to, for example a deal, we would use `ser`:

> (el trato) no *es* muy bueno

If we refer to the condition of something, we would use `estar`:

> ¿Cómo *está* el coche? (meaning *what is the condition of the car?*)
>
> No **está** muy bien.
>
> ¿Cómo *está* la cena? (meaning *how's dinner tonight?*)
>
> (No) **está** muy buena.

And then you have also a problem because `good` can be translated both as `bien` or `bueno`. So "it is (not) very good" could be translated as

- (no) es muy bueno
- (no) está muy bien
- (no) está muy bueno

So basically I think that there could be a lot of options and example did not cover all cases (probably I didn't either in my explanation...). It is not that you can only apply one verb for positive or negative, it is just that the example is not exhaustive.

Answer (score 2):

Another example to explain further how both *ser* and *estar* can be used for good and bad.

> El pastel de chocolate **es** muy bueno

In general, (all) chocolate cake is good.

> El pastel de chocolate **está** muy bueno.

This particular chocolate cake is good.

So you may use either verb, depending on the meaning you want to give your sentence.